# Filter table hiding rows with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html-table

I have a table in razor:

```
<table id="tblCaseTeam">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
            </th>
            <th style="width: 30em;">
                @Html.DisplayColumnNameFor(Model, m => m.Action)
            </th>
            <th style="width: 7em;">
                @Html.DisplayColumnNameFor(Model, m => m.Owner)
            </th>
            <th style="width: 7em;">
                @Html.DisplayColumnNameFor(Model, m => m.Deadline)
            </th>
            <th style="width: 15em;">
                @Html.DisplayColumnNameFor(Model, m => m.Status)
            </th>
            <th style="width: 15em;">
                @Html.DisplayColumnNameFor(Model, m => m.Completed)
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { Id = item.ID })
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Action)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Owner)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Deadline)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Completed)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

With a DDL that has 3 values, completed, all and incomplete.
The last column of my table is a boolean displayed in the table as a checkbox.

I'm looking for a JS that filters the rows (hide and show) depending on the selection of the DDL
If "All" then show all.
If "Complete" then just show the rows with the Complete value true in the last column.
If "Incomplete" then just show the rows with the Complete value false in the last column.

I tried some JQuery but cant find out how to do it

```
$table.find("tr").hide().filter(function () { return XXXX }).show();
```

My ddl:

```
<div id="dropdownlist">
    @Html.DropDownList("Filter", new SelectList(ViewBag.SearchOptionsList, "Value", "Text"))
</div>
```

And the code to know the selected value:

```
var sel = $("#Filter option:selected").text();
```

Question 2: Is it possible to, instead of this JS filtering, do a client side filtering with the model, like putting a Where clause in the table for the model depending on the value of the DDL. But is the table going to refresh accordingly?

Thank you

Comment: If you save-as a copy of the output HTML, you will get loads of jQuery answers quickly. It will not be difficult at all once the naming is obvious. Razor pages put people because of the mental translation it involves (and you can't put razor in a JSFiddle). Re Question 2, there are plenty of third-party client side grids that will allow data filtering much more efficiently than your first question will allow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like

```
 <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr class='@item.Completed ? "complete" : "incomplete"'>
```

then on your drop down do something like

```
$( "#dropdownlist" ).change(function() {
  if ($( this ).val() == 'complete'){
    $(".incomplete").hide();
    $(".complete").show();
  }
  else if ($( this ).val() == 'incomplete'){
    $(".incomplete").show();
    $(".complete").hide();
  }
  else {
    $(".incomplete").show();
    $(".complete").show();
  }
});
```

Comment: I ended up hiding and showing rows, but this answer lead me to the solution.